# Splitting header DIV to allow Nav inside row

Tags: html, css, wordpress

So I currently have my header div working, but with my menu under the div, I need to move my menu into the same div area as the logo, so it shows more in line with the logo itself, rather than slightly below.

I am thinking I just need to redo the header all together, which is fine, but I am wondering if I am able to just edit what I have currently.. Like can two div layers overlay in this sense?  I do not mind coding the menu in manually if easier (using the html code links), rather than using the wordpress menu php calls.

Website: http://outside.hobhob.uk/test/

Code I am editing:

```
<header id="header" role="banner">
    <div class="headwidth">
        <h1 class="logo">
            <?php
                if (!empty($data['iter_normal_site_logo'])) {
            ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo           $data['iter_normal_site_logo']; ?>"></a>
            <?php 
                } else {
                ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a>
                <?php
                }
            ?>
        </h1>
        <nav id="main-nav">
        <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' =>'main-nav','fallback_cb'=>'default_main_nav','container'=>'wda','depth'=>2,'menu_class'=>'sf-menu')); ?>
    </nav>  
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
#header {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10000;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9;
  padding-top: 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px #aaa;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px #aaa;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #aaa;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  -moz-transition: all 1s;
  -o-transition: all 1s;
  -ms-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
}
.headwidth {
  max-width: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.logo {
  color: #29251F;
  font-size: 84px;
  line-height: 1.1;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0;
  text-align:left;
}
.logo a {
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

and:

```
#main-nav {
  padding: 20px 0 0;
}
```

Thanks loads!  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using absolute on the menu on the bottom?

```
#main-nav {
text-align: right;
position: absolute;
bottom: 29px;
right: 0px;
}
```

The code above will give you freedom to move the main nav.

Comment: Perfect, this worked :)

For some reason my dropdown is glitching a bit now.. not sure if this is Chrome or coding.. I am guessing I should repeat this code edit in other areas such as my 'UL' code areas.. 

Thanks!